# Cannot edit AWS Dashboard widgets with green borders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I manage some AWS Cloudwatch Dashboards. I have full admin privs and I often edit the dashboard widgets to add/remove new metrics.

Recently I came across some widgets that I cannot edit (though it does allow me to delete...). These widgets have a green border, and a green checkmark icon in the upper left of the widget.

What is the significance of a green bordered widget? Why isn't it editable?

Example of a green bordered widget:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These might be alarms that have been added to a dashboard.
Green or red border indicating alarm status.

Maybe alarms added to dashboards in certain ways do not make a copy.
I think, I haven't found supporting documentation